# Why remainder(35,10) is -5 when remainder(25,10) is 5 in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, rounding

I am running following query in oracle 11g using Sql Developer.

```
SELECT remainder(25,10),remainder(35,10) FROM dual;
```

**Output**

```
REMAINDER(25,10)       REMAINDER(35,10)       
---------------------- ---------------------- 
5                      -5
```

I can use MOD() to get the desired result, but my question is why it is returning +5 for one and -5 for other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/remainder.php), `REMAINDER(m, n)` is defined as

> m - (n * X) where X is the integer nearest m / n

Apparently, Oracle applies "round to even" when the result of the division is halfway between two numbers:

For `REMAINDER(25, 10)`, you get

```
25 / 10 = 2.5 --> nearest integer is 2 (round to even)
25 - (10 * 2) = 5
```

For `REMAINDER(35, 10)`, you get

```
35 / 10 = 3.5 --> nearest integer is 4 (round to even)
35 - (10 * 4) = -5
```

Comment: i figured it out, but round(2.5) and round(3.5) are returning 3 , 4. And there is no mention of "round to even" in documentation right?

Comment: @Rajeev: The 10g documentation of `ROUND` mentions it, 11g documentation indeed does not: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions135.htm